# deploying nodejs and mongoose app in aws

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to aws and recently I have been able to install node, mongod and also, FTPed project file to the server.

For mongodb,
I'm doing mongo in a separate terminal tab and starting service in another tab. I want to know how can I keep the mongo service running.

For node app,
Right now i'm doing node app in the server. How can I keep it alive too ?

Now the problem, is I open the browser with publicip:portno but nothing happens. How can I locate app and run it in the browser.

my app structure is

```
/
node
mongo
server.js and app related files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Linux/Unix `nohup` command allows you to start commands that ignore the signals associated with the controlling terminal process terminating (SIGHUP). Adding the `&` to the command allows that command to run in the background and sending the output to `/dev/null` will ensure that your disk does not fill up with unnecessary log output. Here are some commands that should work:

```
nohup mongod >/dev/null &
node server.js >/dev/null &
```

Comment: It is usually helpful to provide some explanation along with any code/commands.

Comment: how do I open the app in the browser I tried publicDns:portnumber but it doesnt load, how can I do it ?

Comment: What port are you listening on? Have you opened that port in your security group for your EC2 instance?

Comment: I have a security group with inbound rules, i dont know what am i missing :( im listening on port 5000

Comment: is there a rule to allow HTTP traffic into that machine in port 5000? If there is, add your listen code to the question.

Comment: I have http inbound for port 80 and https at 443 in the rule . looks like they dont allow port change

Comment: you can change the security group to allow 5000 in or - a better idea - is to set up a load balancer to receive on port 80 and forward this to port 5000. If my answer to your other question was good, please accept it.

Comment: yep is running thanx!

Comment: I have performed nohup for mongod and forever start server.js and have been able to run the app on the browser. Now the problem is, if I quit my terminal the app is no longer available so I need to ssh server again only then the app loads. I'm also having trouble getting inside mongo terminal

Comment: Use nohup for both the server and mongod

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Linux/Unix command line issue I think. You can use the node module called forever to run your Node.js process in the background easily.

```
npm install -g forever
forever start YourScript.js
```

You can place an & at the end of the mongod command to place it in the background.

Comment: how do I open the app in the browser I tried publicDns:portnumber but it doesnt load, how can I do it ?

Comment: You need to expose a port in the AWS dashboard and/or possibly setup a route binding in Apache or nginx - which are separate questions to this really.

Comment: Actually, I think just exposing the port in the AWS dashboard should be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in your node app you have the command `app.listen("port number");`

This is the "port number" that you should be using in your browser to render the page with the elastic IP from your AWS instance. Make sure that your elastic IP is configured to accept inbound requests.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the service/app running in the background you can run the `screen` command then launch ur app/service (e.g. `mongod` OR `node app.js`). In the same terminal that your app is running press `control + a + d`, you should see

> (detached)

printed on your screen.

This should keep your app/service running in the background.